# Python if function replying with invalid syntax

Tags: python

I type this in:

```
password=int(input("What is the password?")
if password == 2019:
    print ("You got it right!")
else: 
    print ("You got it WRONG!")
```

and it says that the first print statement is an invalid syntax

Comment: Forgot a closing parenthesis after `int(input("What is the password?")`.

Comment: Welcome the Stackoverflow.  You have two answers that are correct below.  Please select one by clicking the green check mark.  This will reward the person who posted the answer with some reputation and you'll get a mild boost as well.

Answer (score 1):

Friend, you need to close a parenthesis at the end of the line that corresponds to the int function.

```
password=int(input("What is the password?"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
password=int(input("What is the password?"))

if password == 2019:
    print("You got it right!")

else:
    print("You got it WRONG!")
```

Make sure to close your brackets when casting items in python